# Fatal error: Accessing State<Binding<String>> outside View.body

Tags: swiftui

I'm having a problem trying to get textfields working in SwiftUI.
I get `Fatal error: Accessing State> outside View.body` whenever I try to run the following code.

Anyone have a suggestion?

```
struct SearchRoot : View {

    @State var text: String = ""

    var body: some View {
        HStack {
            TextField($text,
                      placeholder: Text("type something here..."))
            Button(action: {
                // Closure will be called once user taps your button
                print(self.$text)
            }) {
                Text("SEND")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I'm running Xcode Version 11.0 beta (11M336w) on macOS 10.15 Beta (19A471t)

Edit: Simplified code, still getting the same error.

```
struct SearchRoot : View {

    @State var text: String = ""

    var body: some View {
            TextField($text,
                      placeholder: Text("type something here..."))
    }
}
```

Comment: Tries both of them. Even the first one compiles for me

Comment: the behavior of SwiftUI on iOS 13.0 regarding accessing state/environment outside of View body has changed in iOS 13.1 onwards, now you can access those vars from anywhere that references the View

Comment: @JAHelia do u have some link to official note?

Comment: @hbk it's not mentioned in the docs, I discovered it by trial

Comment: @JAHelia yes, I also can confirm this, just think that there is might be some doc about this change. Anyway, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eureka! SwiftUI wants a single source of truth.

What I neglected to include in my original code snippets is that this struct is within a tabbed application.

To fix this I needed to define the  `@State var text: String = ""` in the struct that creates the top level TabbedView, then use $Binding in the SearchRoot.

I'm not sure if this is works as designed or just a beta 1 issue, but it's the way it works for now.

```
struct ContentView : View {
    @State private var selection = 0
    @State private var text: String = "searching ex"

    var body: some View {
        TabbedView(selection: $selection){
            ShoppingListRoot().body.tabItemLabel(Text("Cart")).tag(0)
            SearchRoot(text: $text).body.tabItemLabel(Text("Search")).tag(1)
            StoreRoot().body.tabItemLabel(Text("Store")).tag(2)
            BudgetRoot().body
                .tabItemLabel(Text("Budget"))
                .tag(3)
            SettingsRoot().body
                .tabItemLabel(Text("Settings"))
                .tag(4)

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: “What I neglected to include in my original code snippets...” - Well, fortunately, you can edit the question and include the omitted information.

Answer (score 3):

The compiler emits an error if the `$` operator is used outside `body`, in a `View`.
The button initializer is defined as:

> init(action: @escaping () -> Void, @ViewBuilder label: () -> Label)

You're using `$` in an escaping closure, in the **first snippet** of code.

That means the `action` may outlive (*escape*) the `body`, hence the error.

The **second snippet** compiles and works fine for me.

Comment: The first one also compiles to me and let me correct you. You can use bindable object in the `@escaping` body(it happens when you are configuring the `List`), but it should be done carefully, In this case `$` sign is not needed just because the `$` is usually used to pass the property `BindingObject` or `State` into a child view and save to `@Bindable` property